# ASP:UpdatePanel didn't work as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have the following front end code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="groupTable" runat="server"></asp:Table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

where "groupTable" is generated at server side with few row of text box like below

```
<INPUT onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'textbox0\',\'\')', 0)" tabIndex=100 onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id=textbox0 language=javascript value=eeedddeeeee name=textbox0 jQuery19107993684268830612="42">
```

Each text box has post back because there's server side logic that applies to the adjacent controls, so that control's content dependent on the previous control content.

I expect to see the whole page not get refreshed but just the table itself, but it turns out the other way.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Where do you get `__doPostBack(\'textbox0\',\'\')` from?

Comment: from editing the text box.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the Controls are not registered for Async Postback. You can do 2 things. Register those TextBoxes for Async Postback or create the TextBoxes in `groupTable` dynamically from code behind.

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(TextBox1);
```

Or add the TextBoxes directly to `groupTable`

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.AutoPostBack = true;
textBox.Text = "Hello World";
textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged; 

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();

TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
tableCell.Controls.Add(textBox);
tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

groupTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
```